# PowerShell zip script adding many folders

Tags: powershell, zip, compression, directory

how to add many folders from differents places to one file zip in PowerShell script using [io.compression.zipfile]

Comment: Any special reasons to use `[io.compression.zipfile]`? Maybe you're delving into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can check this out for help http://ss64.com/ps/zip.html but you may also want to use 7zip and is CLI

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the Extensions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions(v=vs.110).aspx

A simple example for adding a single file would be as follows

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
$NewFilePath = "c:\pat\to\file.txt"
$EntryName = "file.txt"

$zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::Open("test.zip",[io.compression.ziparchivemode]::Create)
[io.compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $NewFilePath, $EntryName)
$zip.Dispose()
```

You can just iterate over your list of files adding them to your new zip file.

Note that you can reference the type without the full path if you wish.